# Branched Questions

Tags: surveymonkey

I have a question regarding question branching. I have a survey I'm trying to build that has questions that looks like this:

```
1. This is the main question.
   a. this is an answer
      1. this is a sub answer
      2. this is a sub answer
   b. this is an answer
      1. this is a sub answer
      2. this is a sub answer
```

So what would happen in this scenario is the respondant would pick either a or b. I would like only a and b to show initially. Then once the pick one of them, let's say a numbers 1 and 2 under a would show. I think this can be done with page branching but I would rather not use page branching within questions. Page branching is better for going from one questions to another on a different page based on an answer but I wouldn't want to use it for within the same question. Is this possible and if not is there a word around within survey monkey that doesn't require bouncing around to different pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Skip Logic](http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/What-is-Skip-Logic), which is Question Branching, but it is only available for paid Survey Monkey plans.

The basics of Skip Logic: Respondents are directed through different paths of a survey based on how they answer.